# 'Cannot find module' error with ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm developing a Discord bot and I'm using `ytdl-core`, `opusscript` and `ffmpeg-binaries` from `node_module` to do it. The bot works well but, when I use my command for playing music, it doesn't do anything: the only thing it does is connecting to the voice channel and throwing an error in the console. The error says:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ytdl-core'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  at voiceChannel.join.then (/app/index.js:365:36)
  at -anonymous-
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) code: 
'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

I tried to reinstall npm and all my libraries from my project and still throwing the same error. I've also tried to debug it making a new bot, but nothing, the problem continues.

```
case "play":
  let voice - Chan = message.member.voiceChannel;
  let songURL = args.slice(1).join(' ');
  if (!voiceChan || voiceChan.type !== 'voice') {
    message.channel.send('¡You need to join in a Voice Channel First!!.');
  } else if (message.guild.voiceConnection) {
    message.channel.send('I\'m already in a Voice Channel!.');
  } else {
    message.channel.send('Connecting...').then(m => {
      voiceChan.join().then(() => {
        m.edit('Connected!.').catch(error => console.log(error));
        const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
        let voiceChan = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChan) return message.channel.send('You need to join a voice channel!!.');
        if (!songURL) return message.channel.send('Input a Youtube URL .');
        voiceChan.join()
          .then(connection => {
            const url = ytdl(songURL.join(' '), {
              filter: 'audioonly'
            });
            const dispatcher = connection.playStream(url);
            //events:
            dispatcher.on('end', () => {});
            dispatcher.on('error', e => {
              console.log(e);
            });
            //functions: 
            dispatcher.setVolume(0.5);
            dispatcher.time;
            dispatcher.end();
            message.delete();
            message.channel.send('now playing!: ' + songURL);
          }).catch(console.error);
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
  break;
```

Everything works well after you set a URL: if you send a URL the bot doesn't do anything and send that error to the console.

Comment: Did you try `npm i ytdl-core -g`?

Comment: I tried, the problem was solved yesterday, the problem was a saturation of code, I write so much code, I needed a more simple code to made it, and some variables was bad writed. 

[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/91sKaf2V)